# Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range?

Tags: arrays, vba, loops

I am working on VBA and trying to solve the shortest path problem. When I run my code, it alerts me that: "Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range". I feel puzzled. I would be really appreciated if you could point out my error. Thank you in advance.

```
Sub test()

    Dim Per() As Boolean
    ReDim Per(1 To 10)
    Dim Lab() As Long
    ReDim Lab(1 To 10)
    
    Dim i As Long
    
    For i = 1 To 10
        If i = 1 Then
            Lab(i) = 0
            Per(i) = True
        Else
            Lab(i) = 100000
            Per(i) = False
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: There seems to be nothing wrong with this code (works fine for me)

Comment: Thank you for answering, but if I add the statement 'MsgBox (i)', the output is 11. Do you know why does that happen?

Comment: The For Next loop exits when `i` is outside of the limits specified, so the loop will exit when `i` hits 11